# What is the equivalent for a session that holds a user id in PHP?

Tags: android, firebase

In PHP, when a user logs in (talking about simple web apps), I keep his user id in a session that is saved across all pages.
Assuming I have a login to my app (Using Firebase, for example), how do I keep track of the current user id? I want to get the general idea of how it works on Android. Is there some global variable across all fragments/activities?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Firebase Authentication. The user signs in from the device once, and Firebase then maintains their session.

The sign in can either be done with a [pre-built UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui), or by building your own UI and making [calls to the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/).

For either of those, you can [pick up the existing user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in each activity with:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution (if you aren't using Firebase), consider using `SharedPreferences`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Note that this will persist the user id across app restarts as well.

It's super simple to use, which is a benefit:

```
//Save value
getSharedPreferences().edit().putString("my_user_id", userId).apply();

//Retrieve value
String userId = getSharedPreferences().getString("my_user_id", default_value);
```